# Can I create a function that's a property of a function in an object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to access a function within an object like this

```
    function MyObject()
    {
        this.create = function(array)
        {
             var myArray = array;
             this.arrayLength = function(){return myArray.length;}

             // Do something else here...
        }
    }
    var foo = new MyObject();
    foo.create(value);
    console.log(foo.create.arrayLength(););
```

I get undefined as response for .create.length(), is it even possible to do it that way?

Comment: have you tried `console.log(MyObject.create(value).arrayLength(););`?

Comment: This looks very complicated, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Use this : `console.log(foo.arrayLength());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `.create()` method with `foo.create()`, then within `.create()` `this` is `foo`. So this line:

```
this.arrayLength = function(){return myArray.length;}
```

creates a method `arrayLength()` on `foo`. So just use:

```
console.log(foo.arrayLength());
```

If for some reason you actually want `arrayLength()` to be a method of `create` you could do this:

```
this.create.arrayLength = function(){return myArray.length;}
```

and then use your original:

```
console.log(foo.create.arrayLength());
```

(minus the extra semicolon that was before the closing bracket).

But while the latter version "works" it seems kind of a strange way to go.

Answer (score 1):

in :

```
this.create = function(array)
{
     var myArray = array;
     this.arrayLength = function(){return myArray.length;}
}
```

`this` refers to `foo`, because you're calling `create` using `something.create()` instead of `new MyObject.create()` in which case `this` would refer to the instance of `create`. Which means that `arrayLength` is not a property of the function `create`, so you can't call it this way.

```
var foo = new (new MyObject).create();
console.log(foo.create.arrayLength(););
```

Would work however.

If you told us what you want to do we would surely think of a less weird way.

Comment: This won't work. You'd need to add parentheses to the first line: `var foo = (new MyObject).create();` to avoid an error (because `MyObject.create` is undefined; you're trying to call a method of the object returned by `new MyObject`). But then the second line wouldn't work because `foo` would be undefined because `create()` doesn't return a value.

Comment: Yeah `new (new MyObject).create();` my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is so I'll say something I haven't seen yet

```
var foo = new MyObject();
// `foo` has no property _arrayLength_
foo.create([1, 2, 3]); // _create_ sets `this.arrayLength`
// `foo` now has property _arrayLength_
foo.arrayLength(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix to your code with minimum changes:

```
function MyObject() {

  function arrayCreate(array) {
    var myArray = array;
    arrayCreate.arrayLength = function() {
      return myArray.length;
    }
  }

  this.create = arrayCreate;
  // Do something else here...
}
var foo = new MyObject();
foo.create([1,2,3]);
console.log(foo.create.arrayLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

It was explained pretty well above what the problem is.

So to fix it, just change the line where you define the arrayLength method.

Change this line: `this.arrayLength = func...`

To this: `this.create.arrayLength = func...`